# Symfony2 - Page view counter

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, count, counter, pageviews

I am trying to add a page view counter for posts, that are the most viewed by the user. I have added a property $viewCount which is an integer into my Post entity.

I want this to be counted each time the user clicks on the show page for a particular post.

To step through the process, I need to setup a counter, add a +1 each time it's viewed, store this in the database, query for this then pass this back out to Twig.

**The 2 parts I don't know how to do after searching for hrs, is:**

1) How to add each time the user views the page (I know you want to use a +1 somehow)

2) How to query for the most page views to pass to the controller and twig

**showAction**

```
/**
 * Show Post
 *
 * @param $slug
 * @throws \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException
 * @return array
 *
 * @Route("/post/{slug}", name="acme_demo_show")
 * @Template("AcmeDemoBundle:Page:show.html.twig")
 */
public function showPostAction($slug)
{
    $article = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AcmeBundle:Post')
        ->findOneBy(array(
            'slug' => $slug
        ));

    if (null === $article) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException('Post was not found');
    }

    // Increment views each time user clicks on an article
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $views = $article->getViews();
    $article->setViews($views + 1);
    $em->flush();

    return array(
        'article' => $article,
    );
}
```

sidebar action

```
public function sidebarAction()
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $post = $em->getRepository('AcmeDemoBundle:Article')
        ->getMostRecentArticles(5);

    if (!$post) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException('No posts were found');
    }

    $articles = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AcmeDemoBundle:Article')
        ->findBy(array(
            array(
                'views' => 'ASC'
            )
        ));

    return array(
        'post' => $post,
        'articles' => $articles
    );
}
```

Twig

```
<h3>Most Popular Articles</h3>
    {% for article in articles %}
        <a href="{{ path('acme_demo_article_show', { slug: article.slug }) }}" class="anchor" style="text-decoration: none">{{ article.title }}</a><br>
    {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to increment the counter when a user clicks a link you'll need javascript with AJAX. Alternatively you could do it in your post's controller in pure php with something like:

```
$views = $article->getViews();
$article->setViews($views + 1);
$em->persist($article);
$em->flush();
```

The best practice being adding an `increment()` method to your `Article` entity.

Then, to query articles by views:

```
 $articles = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AcmeBundle:Post')
        ->findBy(array(), array('views' => 'ASC'));
```

But better practice is to write you own method in the entity's repository.

Update:

**Repository**

```
public function getMostPopularArticles()
{
    return $this->createQueryBuilder('article')
        ->select('article')
        ->orderBy('article.views', 'DESC')
        ->getQuery()
        ->execute();

}
```

Comment: He would also need to enforce table/row locking or he could not guarantee the correctness of increment

Comment: @jperovic How do you enforce table/row locking?

Comment: Since you're using doctrine there is an article on this: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/transactions-and-concurrency.html

Comment: Your error comes from the findBy method. Use the same syntax I did. First array we can leave empty as we aren't looking for a specific field value, the second array is the orderby clause. And @jperovic is totally right.

Comment: Ok, I fixed it by using the repository code, and the error went away. What did you mean by use the same syntax?

Comment: According to your updated code you used ->findBy(array(array('views' => 'ASC' ))) but it was ->findBy(array(), array('views' => 'ASC' ))

Comment: @Tom Toms You're right, I didn't write down exactly as you had written it, my bad.

Comment: The link to the docs in the comment above now fails, for anyone else arriving here : http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/transactions-and-concurrency.html?highlight=locking#locking-support

Comment: why is locking the table important here ?

Comment: Because there can be cases like: you get the counter from database but before incrementing someone increments it and saves it. Best practice is actually to use a cursor to keep this from happening but this isn't a SQL question so I went with simple and compatible and you'd have to use table locking for that depending on the database (MongoDB for ex. has an incr() method).